# node-ssdp doesn't work with webpack

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, ssdp

I'm using [node-ssdp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssdp) to detect an IOT device connected to the network. Both server code and client code works fine with a sample node project. My client app is in angular-electron with webpack as the module bundler. I installed node-ssdp in the angular project with

```
npm install node-ssdp --save
```

`node-ssdp` gets installed successfully. But then webpack fails with following errors.

```
ERROR in ./~/node-ssdp/test/lib/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chai' in 'J:\fyp\desktop-client\node_modules\node-ssdp\test\lib'
 @ ./~/node-ssdp/test/lib/server.js 3:13-28
 @ ./~/node-ssdp ^.*server$
 @ ./~/node-ssdp/index.js
 @ ./src/app/providers/pd.service.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./~/node-ssdp/test/lib/client.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chai' in 'J:\fyp\desktop-client\node_modules\node-ssdp\test\lib'
 @ ./~/node-ssdp/test/lib/client.js 4:13-28
 @ ./~/node-ssdp ^.*client$
 @ ./~/node-ssdp/index.js
 @ ./src/app/providers/pd.service.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./~/node-ssdp/test/helper.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sinon' in 'J:\fyp\desktop-client\node_modules\node-ssdp\test'
 @ ./~/node-ssdp/test/helper.js 1:12-28
 @ ./~/node-ssdp/test/lib/server.js
 @ ./~/node-ssdp ^.*server$
 @ ./~/node-ssdp/index.js
 @ ./src/app/providers/pd.service.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./~/node-ssdp/test/helper.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in 'J:\fyp\desktop-client\node_modules\node-ssdp\test'
 @ ./~/node-ssdp/test/helper.js 3:12-28
 @ ./~/node-ssdp/test/lib/server.js
 @ ./~/node-ssdp ^.*server$
 @ ./~/node-ssdp/index.js
 @ ./src/app/providers/pd.service.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

I tried installing the above missing `chai, sinon, dgram` dependencies manually.`chai` and `sinon` errors got eliminated but not `dgram`.

I did tried several times and wasted few hours on this. But I was not succeeded. Can anyone suggest a solution please?

Comment: What [target](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) are you using in your Webpack configuration?

Comment: @robertklep I'm not familiar with webpack. Can you please tell me how to find it? I'm building for electron anyway.

Comment: Does your project have a file called `webpack.config.js`? The target should be set in there. If it isn't in there, Webpack will default to the `web` target, which in your case isn't the right one.

Comment: Yes it's there. This is it https://hastebin.com/lowojuhika.js

Comment: Yes `webpack.config.js` there. But target has not been set. This is 
`webpack.config.js` https://hastebin.com/lowojuhika.js . What is the target to be set for an electron app? Is it `electron-main` or `electron-renderer`?

Comment: Not sure, but I guess it'd be easy to try both and see if that solves your issue (although looking at the config, you may also need to remove some entries in the `node` property, all the way down)

Comment: @robertklep tried both for target. But didn't work. I think this is some incompatibility issue of node-ssdp with webpack.

Comment: Why didn't it work? Did you get errors? Did you remove any entries from the `node` property in the configuration file?

Comment: Yes I got the same error. I didn't remove any property from configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking at this, dgram was deprecated by npm, but was adopted by node. Here's the source code for dgram https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v20.5.1/lib/dgram.js.